# Accessing SOAP service works only from Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap

I'm trying to access SOAP service from my android app.

I was testing my request using http://www.requestmaker.com/ so I end up with this request:

**Request Headers Sent:**

```
POST /WebserviceHCX.asmx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: hcxwords/installAcknowledge
Host: webservice.hcxwords.eu
Accept-Charset: utf-8
Accept: text/xml,application/text+xml,application/soap+xml
Content-Length: 382
```

**Request Data:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <installAcknowledge xmlns="hcxwords">
      <deviceID>test</deviceID>
      <refCode2></refCode2>
    </installAcknowledge>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Since this worked perfectly well (200 OK) in http://www.requestmaker.com/ I just wanted to do the same thing in my android app.

```
    final String SOAPRequestXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><installAcknowledge xmlns=\"hcxwords\"><deviceID>"+deviceID+"</deviceID><refCode2>"+refCode2+"</refCode2></installAcknowledge></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";

    String url = "http://webservice.hcxwords.eu/WebserviceHCX.asmx";

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

    httppost.addHeader("Content-type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8"); 
    httppost.addHeader("SOAPAction", "hcxwords/installAcknowledge");
    httppost.addHeader("Host", "webservice.hcxwords.eu");
    httppost.addHeader("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
    httppost.addHeader("Accept", "text/xml,application/text+xml,application/soap+xml");


    StringEntity se;

    try {
        se = new StringEntity(SOAPRequestXML, HTTP.UTF_8);
        se.setContentType("text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
        se.setContentEncoding("utf-8");
        httppost.setEntity(se);

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        BasicHttpResponse httpResponse =
                (BasicHttpResponse)httpclient.execute(httppost);
        return httpResponse;

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new IllegalStateException("ClientProtocolException ");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new IllegalStateException("IOException ");
    }
```

This work great in my Emulator(200 OK) by on my Nexus 4 it's (404) and on my samsung tablet it throws IOException:

> IOException: Unable to resolve host "webservice.hcxwords.eu": No address associated with > hostname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the cause is that the emulator is on the same network as the web server (thus allowing the hostname to be resolved) yet the devices are not.

Two possible solutions:

1. Use VPN to get your device on the network (assuming that the network supports VPN).  JunosPulse is a good free VPN client you can download to your Android device.
2. Expose the web server outside of the firewall.  You may not be in a position to do this however.  Option 1 is usually your best bet.

Another possibility js that something is preventing the device from resolving the server name.  Try to access the server by IP address, e.g:

```
String url = "http://<ip_address_of_server>/WebserviceHCX.asmx";
```

Comment: Yes but the emulator may be behind the same firewall in which case it is able to resolve the name.  Clearly the device cannot resolve the name.

Comment: Try changing your URL so that it references the server by IP address and not by name.

Comment: yeah, I get it now... it's now working everywhere! Thanks a lot.